# How to input confirmation box in array_column php

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is my coding. I have try put onclick in the array but there is problem with the json file. I use datatable to show the array. This is my first time using the array_column php and server side processing. Right now, if i press delete, it will directly delete the item without any confirmation box. I try put the onclick function in the  and pass it to proDelete.php but the function didn't work. Is there any problem with my code? If it is, just tell me. Willingly to learn more and achieve more.

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'prodid', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'prodname',      'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'prodbrand',     'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'compstatus',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'fldtkh_tamat',
        'dt'        => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'jS M Y', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'prodid',
        'dt'        => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            **return '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="proDelete.php?id=' . $d . '">Delete</a>';**
        }
```

This is the proDelete.php code.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$data_ids = $_REQUEST['id'];
$data_id_array = explode(",", $data_ids); 
if(!empty($data_id_array)) {
    foreach($data_id_array as $id) {
        $stmt_delete=$connect->prepare('DELETE FROM view_tblcomp_product WHERE prodid=:uid');
        $stmt_delete->bindParam(':uid', $_GET['id']);
        if($stmt_delete->execute())
        {
            ?>
            <script>
            alert("You have deleted one product");
            window.location.href=('products.php');
            </script>
            <?php 
        }else 
        ?>
            <script>
            alert("Can not delete item");
            window.location.href=('products.php');
            </script>
            <?php 
    }
}?>
```

Can someone help me with the code? Hope you guys can help me with the code. I am newbie in PHP developer. Thank you guys. Appreciate you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

`<a class="btn btn-danger" href="proDelete.php?id=' . $d . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this item?\')>Delete</a>`

It will prompt you with a dialog where you can click OK (go ahead and delete) or Cancel (don't follow the link, hence no deletion).

Comment: I have tried it. Thanks bro. Its working for me. Thanks a lot.